# Tomcat change password will it affect running application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I have installed tomcat server and I forgot my username/passoword.  I have edited my `tomcat-user.xml` file like this:

```
  <role rolename="manager"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
```

Now my tomcat-manager working fine.

Two questions:

1. If anybody knew my previous password, will they be able to access my tomcat-manager?
2. Once I added the tomcat username and password, will it affect immediately or do I have to restart?

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just try it yourself locally?

Comment: i am not the very best person to ans , but once you make configuration level change your application misses the effect until server restarted  , even your new username password will not be affected unless you restart the server

Comment: 2nd question i have tried . Not effect, if our application use tomcat authentication only it will affect, otherwise no. But first I couldn't try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to your question below.

1) Well, It depends on the domain you both are and the server where you locate your tomcat. (If you setup your tomcat in a public server and its password is known by many people, you are in trouble).

Better to reset the password to be in a safer side.

2) You must stop the tomcat instance, reset your password and The server must be restarted before changes to configuration settings will take effect.

Comment: Once I changed the password, if i restart tomcat server, will it effect running application?